# Controlling the orientation of Fill Surface Definition CATIA V5

Tags: vba, catia

I'm using a power copy with a fill surface to create surfaces from lines. However, the resultant surface has varying orientations which is affecting the rest of my model. It seems the only thing that has randomly changed is the orientation of the fill.

Is there any way to control the orientation of the fill when it is created? There doesn't seem to be any option from the control panel.

Failing that, any explanation as to why it might be changing orientation?

I've made sure that all the lines are the same orientation on each instance but it seems the fill surface randomly changes orientation.

Comment: How about to include an invert feature in your PowerCopy, so you can change the direction of your fill surface.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is sometimes it is orientated in 1 direction and sometimes in another. So an invert would just switch it for both but wouldn't align them in the same orientation.

Comment: You could try to use a Knowledgeware Rule for that: create a surface via rule, switching between an assemble and an invert by measure the normal of the fill (very complex rule)

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to avoid any complex rules like that...